# capture m3u8 from live streaming website

Tags: vlc, m3u8, wms

Is it possible to extract m3u8 with wmsAuthsign? Here is the link we were provided : http://cdn01.iqbroadcast.tv:8081/g1/punt56ds/playlist.m3u8?wmsAuthSign=c2VydmVyX3RpbWU9Ni8yNC8yMDE2IDEwOjUyOjM4IFBNJmhhc2hfdmFsdWU9QXI4MlJTUitETWt6YTBYdGU2T0lBUT09JnZhbGlkbWludXRlcz0yMA==

Ideally we would like to run live via VLC - but because wmsAuthSign is not fixed string, it changes every time.

Comment: contact the site owner and request an api to discover the URL.

Comment: Thanks - I guess that is the only solution available to us.